# What is the practicality of a single domain with nearly unlimited automatically updated A records for new servers in the wild?

Tags: security, dns, domain

I hope this question falls within the guidelines here at superuser, and my apologies in advance if it falls short. If it does, please leave a comment and I will delete.

I'm theorizing a system which would allow a single domain name to be disbursed among any number of servers. The idea behind this is a decentralized communications platform with many "node" servers that anyone could establish by downloading a prepackaged VM, but I would want only one domain name to serve them all.

(The nodes would only be there to proxy peer-to-peer communication (e.g. temporarily pass data about one peer to another). They would never store any secure or private information.)

To do this, I envision scripting automatic DNS record creation done at the main server that I control. So, once a new server is brought online, it would notify my server to add a new A record for that new server, and my server would then update DNS programatically. The way I would do this is using cloudflare and the [Cloudflare API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-update-dns-record)

I read in this [link](https://www.quora.com/How-many-A-host-records-can-a-domain-have) the maximum theoretical number of A records for a domain is 65535 records due to SOA overhead. So, it seems that it would be technically possible for at least ~65,000 records.

What I need to understand is whether or not this idea is even practical. Are there other things I should be concerned with like security that I'm overlooking? There probably are...please go easy on me :)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is practical and can be used for crude load balancing.  There are practical limits though, as while this can balance load (crudely) it will not provide failover.  It may be better to have a few A records pointing to load balances so the balances can ensure availability and reduce the amount of DNS traffic.

(As an aside, large DNS results are sent over port 53 but on TCP which is blocked by some clueless admins, so you may experience more reachability issues then you envisage).